# Tab navigation React Native hide part of bottom menu buttons

Tags: react-native

I am new to this field and have been puzzling over this question for several days. Now I have three screens and three buttons.
I try to do next.

When I click on a middle button I want to hide left and right buttons and change active button's image.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This code from documentation with a small modification
when I click on right button I want to switch left and middle buttons

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              return (
                <Ionicons
                  name={
                    focused
                      ? 'ios-information-circle'
                      : 'ios-information-circle-outline'
                  }
                  size={size}
                  color={color}
                />
              );
            } else if (route.name === 'Settings') {
              return (
                <Ionicons
                  name={focused ? 'beaker' : 'ios-list'}
                  size={size}
                  color={color}
                />
              );
            }  else if (route.name === 'Test') {
              return (
                <Ionicons
                  name={focused ? 'basketball' : 'aperture'}
                  size={size}
                  color={color}
                />
              );
            }
          },
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
          tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato',
        })}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ tabBarBadge: 3 }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Test" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```